# How to serve a computationally intensive application via REST?

Tags: c++, rest, performance, node.js, message-queue

I have got a native image processing application that can enhance photos(peApp). Now, I want to serve this functionality to the world by having a server application that supports REST. Now while taking the scalability into account, I think I better seperate this project into 3 components:

- peApp : does only his computationally intensive job (may use GPU)
- zeroMQ(or another mq) : a message queue application that can organize request
- node.js & express based web service(or maybe a native app) : provides REST and puts requests into message queue.

Now my questions are:

- Are those **TYPE** of components the right choice? (I'm not asking if I should use zeroMQ, I'm asking if using a message queue application is sound)
- In terms of scalability, will I eventually need a middleware?
- What are the best practices about such systems? (a heavy duty app and serving it)
- How can I achieve a bidirectional communication/notification?

Comment: see [Green fields, blue skies, and the white board - what is too broad?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6961/31260)

Comment: The only question you've asked here that *might* be answerable is the last one about bidirectional communication.  Please read [this](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6961/) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142353)..

Comment: @gnat: I am not asking "how to do this", I already have a design.

Comment: You are mistaken if you think the purpose of middleware is scalability.

Comment: The key to scaling a CPU intensive task is that you know how you're going to eventually apply lots of CPUs/GPUs to the task.  That will start with multiple CPUs/GPUs within a computer and then will expand to multiple computers.  So, you need to figure out how you can start simple, but eventually scale it to multiple boxes all sharing the load.  There are many ways to do that.

Comment: So peApp is the only thing here that actually addresses your CPU-intensive task?  The rest of the technologies you've mentioned here are essentially window dressing; you may need one or more of them, but only to prevent your cpu-intensive task from blocking.

Comment: @jfriend00 : I'm thinking the middleware as a glue between my web service and my worker app which may increase in the number instances and as the demand rise

Comment: What you need is a non-blocking server that can handle your CPU-intensive tasks.  But that can be done in many different ways, and so can providing a REST interface.  What will be your criteria for choosing your remaining components?

Comment: Let me put this to you another way:  how can you re-word your first two bullets so that the answers are not merely "yes" or "no?"

Comment: I'm being persistent about this for a reason: *asking good questions is hard.*  Answering bad (i.e. vague, too broad, unclear) questions is even harder.  You're expecting us to give you some assurance that you've made the "right" choices.  We can't give you that assurance, because you've given us no insight into your decision-making process.  If there is such a thing as a "right" choice, it is a choice made after evaluating all of the costs and benefits of each approach, and deciding on the approach that is the best fit for your specific requirements...

Comment: It makes sense to have a web server handling the incoming requests, some sort of work queue for pending jobs and multiple worker processes running the jobs with a mechanism for communicating completion and the rest back to the web server so it can deliver the result.  Done right, you probably don't need to scale the web server beyond a single process because a single process there can handle a lot of requests.  The worker processes should be designed to scale to both multiple CPUs within a computer and multiple computers.

Comment: @RobertHarvey : My criteria is performance and extendibility. Because I can bundle everything(server and the worker) in a single executable and put them in different threads and adjust affinities, or node.js can act as a mq beside being a web service, etc. Problem is that I cannot foresee the possible problems of all those choices. That's why I'm asking for experience rather than a solid technical information which unfortunately makes me ask question including the words "best practices". Thank you

Comment: I'm unsure if the queue needs to be anything more than an array of pending jobs held by the web server so as one finishes, it dishes off the next one in order to the workers.  I'm sure you could use an mq for that, but I'm not sure whether you need to.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of us can foresee all of the possible problems you may have with *any* technical choices you make.  Your best bet is to stand up a small prototype of your proposed architecture, and evaluate it on its merits.  Does that take work?  Of course it does.  But that's what any of us here would do if we were evaluating any technology that is new to us.  Your best way to become informed about your technological choices is to be "hands-on."

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you. The queue is only there to save the web service from the burden of organizing jobs.

Comment: Well figure out how your peApp worker processes are going to get jobs and communicate results back to the web server while doing that from multiple processes in multiple computers and then you'll know whether or not you want a MQ to help you do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, @RobertHarvey's comment that "none of us can foresee all of the possible problems" is generally correct, and as he suggests you should probably prototype out your solution and setup good metrics to figure out where it needs to scale.

That said, I think based on your description your approach is reasonable.  If you want to have a RESTful API, that API will need to accept a POST or PUT with the image(s) that are to be enhanced.  You don't want to block the request, so you accept it immediately and drop the file somewhere so that the image processor can process it later (on a different process or even a different machine).  That 'somewhere' could be a S3 bucket or a file system location or a message queue or anywhere; I don't think we can evaluate what's best for you in that case.

What I would look for in terms of performance and scalability are:

1) Have I divided the components in such a way that I *only* need to expand the places that are the bottleneck.  For example, if you expect that you'll need to run multiple machines that are using peApp, then that needs to be isolated and only contain code needed to run that process.

2) Given #1, do my other process have the infrastructure they need in order to perform without injecting logic into the other components needlessly.  For example, you add a MQ because you don't want your REST app to directly call peApp.  this makes sense.

Beyond those two factors, it's a lot of optimizing for your specific problem.  If it's me, I'd start off w/o the MQ frankly, and just have peApp ping a well known location (e.g. a bucket on S3) to get the 'next' file in the pile to process.  I'd watch lag times CPU(GPU) load and so on to decide if I need to scale out or scale up. Then I'd solve the next problem when those are sorted out.